# “This post has been deleted” banner appears multiple times if post is undeleted between deletions

Tags: bug, status-declined, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I encountered this issue when flaggin a question as dupe and suggesting the OP to rephrase his question or write a new one alltogether since it turned out they needed information on a different topic.

The OP ended up deleting their question while I left the tab open in my browser. When I looked at the page again I found two banners underneath each other. Is this intended/by design or would that qualify as a bug/unwanted behaviour?

Browser: Chrome, version 86.0.4240.75.

[image: Screenshot browser]

[image: Screenshot inspection]

Comment: Kinda sorta. It was deleted, undeleted, and redeleted, triggering a double deletion notification. Undeletion didn't clear the first one, so while this is technically a bug, it isn't really worth fixing. Double deletion happens extremely rarely anyway

Comment: This isn’t specific to Stack Overflow, but I didn’t find a report about this issue on Meta Stack Exchange. I did notice this on two occasions, though, and made chat aware of it: [\[1\]](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8520923#8520923), [\[2\]](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8562294#8562294).

Comment: @Zoe interesting - thanks for the info.. I agree that technically it's sort of 'unclean' while the chances of this scenario reoccuring for a lot of users is very slim..

Comment: I've seen this on multiple occasions and couldn't figure out why! I agree that need for it to be fixed is low, but an explanation for the reason is a blessing :)

Comment: @Scratte I always assumed it was status bydesign. But now I am not sure.

Comment: Related: ["This post has been deleted" message while viewing a post in a deleted state](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/371615/289905).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug. But it is such a rare edge case (with no adverse effects other than seeing the notification twice) that we are going to decline it, as it will take away too much time from other things.

Comment: I'd looked at detecting the realtime deleted notices for another project, so just dumping information here. If, at some point in the future, someone does choose to resolve it, adding something like: `/* A <a name="new-answer"> may be between an answer and a previously inserted .realtime-post-deleted-notification.*/ if ($post.css('opacity') === '0.1' && $post.prev('.realtime-post-deleted-notification').add($post.prev(':not(.answer,.question)').prev('.realtime-post-deleted-notification')).length > 0) { /* Do nothing*/ return; }` just after the first `var` in `postDeleted()` should solve it.

Comment: However, a better solution would be to add a specific class like "realtime-marked-as-deleted" to the `$post` as a flag when first marking it as realtime-deleted and then test for the `$post` having that class in order to stop processing an additional `post-deleted` message for that post. That would be less complex and more assured of definitely determining that the `postDeleted()` code had been run on the post.

Answer (score 6):

I've been able to reproduce this. I've added this to our backlog to address, but this is admittedly low priority for us. Once we get around to revisiting this, will update more here. Adding [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.